# SQL: Find the row COUNT(*) within the tables that have a specific column

Tags: sql, count, find, sql-server-2016, rowcount

Microsoft SQL 2016/13.0: What I'm attempting to do is add a COUNT(*) to this query. What this query does - It finds the tables of a common naming convention (many tables with a common prefix) and out of those tables - what tables have the specific column name. So far so good - it works! What I need next is, within these tables, are there any "rows" (of data) and if so, how many rows in each table. Thanks in advance for helping out, greatly appreciated!. 
Cheers!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #result
GO

CREATE TABLE #result(
   DatabaseName           [nvarchar](128),
   TableName              [nvarchar](128),
   ColumnName             [nvarchar](128),
   --NumOfRows            int NOT NULL, -- COUNT COLUMN
 )
GO

EXEC RunOnAllDataBases'
SELECT 
  {DatabaseName},
  t.name AS TableName, 
  c.name AS ColumnName
  --COUNT(*) AS NumOfRows --COUNT THE ROWS

FROM sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE ''SPECIFIC COLUMN NAME''
AND (t.name LIKE ''COMMON_TABLE_NAME_%')

{ - SOMEWHERE IN HERE I NEED THE COUNT QUERY - }

ORDER BY TableName;
',
'INSERT into #result';

SELECT * FROM #result
--WHERE NumOfRows > 0 
--ORDER BY NumOfRows DESC

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #result
GO
```

Here is what became the solution (there is one error - Must declare the scalar variable - not sure how to fix, although if anyone sees where, please feel free to comment) - very much appreciated. 
Cheers!

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #result
GO

CREATE TABLE #result (
   [EnterpriseID]             [uniqueidentifier], 
   [EnterpriseName]           nvarchar](100), 
   MY_COUNT_COLUMN            int,  
   MyApp_TableName            [nvarchar](500)
   )
GO

EXEC RunOnAllDataBases'
DECLARE @myresults table (
    [EnterpriseID]             [uniqueidentifier], 
    [EnterpriseName]           [nvarchar](100), 
    MY_COUNT_COLUMN            int,
    MyApp_TableName            [nvarchar](500)
  ) 

DECLARE @MyApp_TableName nvarchar(500)
DECLARE qrylist CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT t.name AS MyApp_TableName 

FROM sys.tables AS t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE ''SPECIFIC COLUMN NAME''
AND (t.name LIKE ''COMMON_TABLE_NAME_%')
ORDER BY MyApp_TableName;

OPEN qrylist

FETCH NEXT FROM qrylist
INTO @MyApp_TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
print @MyApp_TableName
declare @cnt int = 0;

exec sp_executesql N''@MyApp_TableName'', 
                   N''@rowcount int output'', @cnt output;

INSERT into @myresults (
            [EnterpriseID], 
            [EnterpriseName],               
            MY_COUNT_COLUMN,
            MyApp_TableName
 )   

SELECT {entid},
       {dbname},
       @cnt,
       @MyApp_TableName

FETCH NEXT FROM qrylist INTO @MyApp_TableName
END

CLOSE qrylist
DEALLOCATE qrylist

SELECT * from @myresults',
'INSERT into #result';

SELECT * FROM #result

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #result
GO
```

Comment: You forgot to mention (and tag) your DBMS.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Can you just provide the query that works please, without the attempted addition?

Comment: I figured it out.. if anyone is interested I can post my solution. Question is officially closed - Sept 14th Cheers!